# Too many "and"s? Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, repetition

A friend of mine (a non-native speaker of English) has asked me to check her CV and I'm afraid / ashamed to say, I'm having trouble.

Are there too many "and"s in the given sentence? It seems OK to me, but I've always heard we shouldn't use so many in one sentence. Here it is:

> I help individuals, schools and organisations to provide special needs care, care training and home audits by providing training classes, carer evaluations and other care-based educational services.

There are many sentences that look similar. Again, they all look OK to me, but this is at odds with what I learned in school. All I could find on the subject was the "Oxford comma", which doesn't seem to be the problem here.

They tend to follow this pattern:

I work with x, y and z to provide x, y and z.

Comment: I would suggest using "care-giver" instead of "carer". Also, I'd say "schools and *other* organizations" since schools are organizations. Lastly, I'd say "provide" rather than "to provide".

Comment: @David Schwartz: I'm glad you caught that one. I obviously misunderstood what the OP meant by "carer". Thank you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Isn't "carer" or "caregiver" dependent on the locale? In the UK, "carer" is correct. According to my (British) English Dictionary, "caregiver" is a North American term?

Comment: @David Schwartz: Thanks for the quick response. I think "carer" is acceptable in British English and I believe "help" can be used with to-infinitives and bare-infinitives. Although many Americans seem to prefer "help" with a bare-infinitive.

Comment: @w3d: You're correct about this, unfortunately: [carer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carer_). I think it unfortunate because shortening the word causes problems. There's no problem with "caregiver": it's clear & unambiguous. There is a problem with :carer": it looks like a misspelling or "career" or "carrier". The technical term in the biomedical field is "caregiver", even though "carer" appears almost as often (31K+ to 33K+) in the [PubMed database of biomed articles](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed). When searching for "carer", the search engine asks: "Did you mean: career (36867 items)".

Comment: @user37373: You're right, but it's not "many Americans": it's "American English", a dialect difference, not a bunch of wrongheaded individuals, which is what your comment implies.

Comment: @BillFranke: I'm curious, which search engine suggests "career" when searching for "carer"? Having tried both google.co.uk (which I wouldn't have expected the suggestion) and google.com, even when logged out in _incognito mode_ I cannot trigger this suggestion?

Comment: @W3D: The [PubMed search engine](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there are too many "and"s in the sentence, but perhaps one of the "provide"s can be changed to "offer", e.g.:

> I help individuals, schools, and organisations **offer** special needs care, care training, and home audits by **{providing / giving [CHOOSE ONE]}** training classes, caregiver evaluations, and other care-based educational services.

or

> I help individuals, schools, and organisations **provide** special needs care, care training, and home audits: I **{give / conduct [CHOOSE ONE]}** training classes, caregiver evaluations, and other care-based educational services.

I like the Oxford comma, but it's not necessary. **[EDIT]:** It's necessary to change "carer" to "caregiver", as David Schwartz suggests in his comment above, though. I misunderstood what you meant by that word "carer" (thought it was supposed to be "career") and offered bad advice about spelling it correctly. People who provide care are normally called "**caregivers**" in the biomedical world.

If your friend is going to provide lists, there will almost always be a need for an "and" in the list. As long as the "and" isn't used to conjoin separate sentences (e.g., I ate and apple, and I drank a cup of coffee, and then I watched TV, and I fell asleep during the program, and then I went to bed), there should be no problem.

OTOH, if all the sentences have the same syntactic structure, then the CV will be boring.

If the sentences are in the cover letter, then they should have more varied structures. If they're in the CV proper, then don't have to be complete sentences but can be something like this:

> Give training classes, caregiver evaluations, and other care-based educational services.
>
> Help individuals, schools, and organisations offer special needs care, care training, and home audits.
>
> Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm convinced that the "and"s can stay. I will take the rest into consideration too. Thank you.

Comment: As stated in other comments, *carer* is **absolutely correct** in British English.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, it is, but it's still unfortunate. See my comment above. "Correct" isn't always "good".

Comment: I've never seen *carer* confused with *career* before. Perhaps that's because I'm more used to seeing *carer* than "care-giver" (which I haven't encountered frequently at all despite some association with caring environments), but it's usually unambiguous in context.

Comment: @Andrew: I can understand that. I've never seen "carer" before. Even in context here it rang no bell. It's a word that should be written only (it sounds not euphonious to my ears). I've seen "rarer", potato "parer", & secret "sharer"; I've heard "barer" & "darer" (jocular with "daree"); & I've been reading biomed articles in British & American & European journals every day for 16 years: "carer" = "[no-see-um](http://keysmosquito.org/no-see-ums/)". If you're used to seeing & hearing a word & know the meaning, then it's always more present for you than for someone not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

"I help individuals, schools and organisations to provide special needs care, care training and home audits by providing training classes, carer evaluations and other care-based educational services." (in a way you have repeated yourself here by mentioning 'training classes' and 'care training')

Service provider,(in this context it means you are providing a service to do with anything concerning the said job in hand and not meaning internet service provider)

As a service provider, I help in providing special needs care and home audit packages which include training classes/courses, carer evaluation and other care-based educational services to individuals, schools and organisastions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Am I to assume then, from your "correction", that the answer to the original question is: there are not too many "and"s?